# Monotone convergence theorem for sequences in a completely metrizable totally ordered topological space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, metrizability

In the Reals it is commonly known that a monotone bounded sequence is convergent. This is due to the first countability axiom of the metric space and the least upper bound property of the reals. Can we affirm that this is true also for sequences in a completely metrizable topological space, where the topology is the order topology generates by the total order?

Comment: Does it have a 'monotone sequence' in a 'completely metrizable topological space' meaning?

Comment: How do you define 'monotone' and 'bounded' in a completely metrisable top space?

Comment: I edited, sorry, the topology is the one generated by a total order we assume on it. Therefore, we can define a notion of monotonicity and boundedness. Sorry again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No : take $\mathbb R \times \{0,1\}$ ordered lexicographically ($0<1$) with the following distance : $d((x,i), (y,j))=d(x,y)+ |i-j|$.

I claim that this metrizes the order topology, and is complete. Once we prove this, the claim will easily follow, because any Cauchy sequence must have, from some rank, the second coordinate constant, and then we use the fact that $\mathbb R$ is complete, and then that $(n,0)$ is monotone and bounded (by, say $(0,1)$) but does not converge.

To prove the claim, we show that opens in both topologies are open in the other one.

Let $U$ be open in the order topology, and $(x,i)\in U$. Then there are $a,b$ such that $(x,i)\in ]a,b[ \subset U$. Up to changing their second coordinates, we may assume $a,b$ both have $i$ as a second coordinate, and then we may take them small enough so that $a=(x-\epsilon, i), b = (x+\epsilon, i)$ with $\epsilon <1$.

Then $]a,b[ = B((x,i), \epsilon)$ which is open in the metric topology. So $U$ is open in the metric topology.

Conversely let $U$ be open in the metric topology and let $x\in U$. Then there is $\epsilon$ with $B(x, \epsilon)\subset U$. Up to taking $\epsilon <1$, $B(x,\epsilon)$ only consists of people with the same second coordinate as $x$, and so can be seen to be of the form $I\times \{i\}$, with $i$ the second coordinate of $x$, and $I$ an open interval of $\mathbb R$; which is open for the order topology. So $U$ is open for the order topology and we are done.

Comment: Thank you very much for the nice counterexample! What if we add connectedness and separability of the space? Can we the have a monotone and bounded sequence that converges? (I am just trying to isolate the properties of the real line that guarantee the proposition to hold). Thanks again!

Comment: Well the space I gave is separable; just not connected. Why are you not satifsied with "it's the upper bound property" ? I think connectedness will do the trick as well : let $U= \{x\mid \exists n, u_n \geq x\}, V = \{x\mid \forall n, u_n< x\}$. Assume $(u_n)$ is strictly increasing and bounded. Then $U$ is open, and $U\sqcup V = X$, $U,V\neq \emptyset$, so it follows that $V$ can't be open. Let $y\in V$ with no open neighbourhood in $V$. So let $z<y$. Then $]z, +\infty[$ is open and contains $y$, so it can't be contained in $V$, so there is $x\in ]z,+\infty[\cap U$. But this implies $z\in U$

Comment: From this it follows that $y$ is the least upper bound of $(u_n)$. And now you can use the connectedness again to prove that $u_n\to y$ : indeed in the above argument, we get $x\in ]z+\infty[\cap U$, but so we also get $u_n \in ]z,+\infty[\cap U$, so $u_n\in ]z,y]$, so for any $z<y, a>y, u_n\in ]z,a[$  : $u_n \to y$